# How Can I Verify store code in mysql and update the table if result return true

Tags: php, mysql

Someone should please help me verify whether this code is right. I want to generate ID base on Pin from pin table under Pin column and insert into pin table in the appid column. The error I am receiving is "Notice: Undefined index: appid in C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\Compet_loginID.php on line 11". Which means appid column is not found and it is there.

```
$num = rand(98564654, 415231564); 
 If(isset($_POST['login'])){
$Pin='';
$ID =$_POST['appid'];
if($Pin=='Pin'){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin WHERE Pin  == '$Pin'");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!$result)
mysql_query("UPDATE pin SET appid ='$num' WHERE Pin = '$Pin'")
            or die(mysql_error()); 
header("location:compet_applicant.php");
```

My Form has ID as the variable and login as a submit button while a `$num` is generated on top to be copied and pasted in the ID variable field.

Comment: Show us your form and ensure that the field `appid` is set like you did with `$_POST['login']`. Also your title is rather misleading, you should make the title about the question which in this case is the error you are encountering.

Comment: My Form has ID as the variable and login as a submit button while a $num is generated on top to be copied and pasted in the ID variable field.

Answer (score 0):

just try to write your query some thing like this with providing escape character ( ` ) to your field name.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pin SET 'appid' ='$num' WHERE 'Pin' = '$Pin'");
```

Comment: Here is my problem `$ID =$_POST['appid'];` appid column is not found in mysql table. How can i fix it?

Comment: can you post code of your form? please make sure the you are getting value in $_POST["appid"]. your form must have field name appid.

Comment: Form Code is too long to enter in comment area

Comment: Here is part of it `<form action="" method="post" name="frm">``<input type="submit" name="login" id="but_sub" value="LOGIN" style="margin:5px;" />`

Comment: please provide your post variable data like echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);